# Server.execute is not preserving querystring data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using server.execute in one resolve aspx, there i will execute relavant aspx based different conditions. But querystring data is not preserving for the target page.

In detail i am passing some query string data to a1.aspx, in a1.aspx i put Server.Execute("/sample/a2.aspx", true)  and trying to get result from a2.aspx by using same query string data available for a1.aspx.

**Code Example:** Server.Execute("/sample/sample.aspx", true);

Please help if anybody have idea about this....thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you want to do and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please show relevant code, the URL you use and how you determine that the query string is not being propagated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the Querystring onto other page. Please use Sessions. Its the most usual way of accessing some variables in multiple pages during Page Calls.